# Spring boot : Configure Two DataSources in the same package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to configure two datasource for my spring boot project, but I have same entities in the two databases, so I ask if it is possible to make the entities in one package and initialise the specific datasource in the repositories.

This my configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class NwlConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties source1DataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "source1")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSource source1DataSource() {
        return source1DataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("source2.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties source2DataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "source2")
    @ConfigurationProperties("source2.datasource")
    public DataSource source2DataSource() {
        return source2DataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Are you getting any error with above config?

Answer (score 0):

Your Configuration looks ok. Only thing is you need to assign which Configuration will be used for which Repository.

If there are multiple entities you can put them in a common package.

Like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "barEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "barTransactionManager", basePackages = {"com.foobar.bar.repo"})
public class BarDbConfig {
```

Complete Code

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "barEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "barTransactionManager", basePackages = {"com.foobar.bar.repo"})
public class BarDbConfig {

  @Bean(name = "barDataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bar.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "barEntityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean barEntityManagerFactory(
      EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("barDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.foobar.bar.domain").persistenceUnit("bar")
        .build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "barTransactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager barTransactionManager(
      @Qualifier("barEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory barEntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(barEntityManagerFactory);
  }

}
```

2nd Datasource Config Class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
    basePackages = {"com.foobar.foo.repo"})
public class FooDbConfig {

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "dataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
      EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.foobar.foo.domain").persistenceUnit("foo")
        .build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
      @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
  }
}
```

Refer [this article](https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7) for more Detail

Comment: I think you don't understand my problem, I do not want to separate the entities in two packages because I have same entites in the two databases. So I want a way to tell spring that repository will use that datasource but make all repositories and entities in one package like that com.foobar.repo.